# Selenium save screenshot is imprecise

Tags: python, selenium

I got this code mostly working except that the images saved are not really adequate. My x, y, width, height take screenshots that are not matching the images. I think there is a better way to do this but I don't know how. Any help appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from PIL import Image
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://superrare.com/features/rare-steals-1")
time.sleep(2)



imgsrc2 = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'slide selected')]")))                                                                                                            

#the element with longest height on page
ele=driver.find_element("xpath", '//div[@id="root"]')
total_height = ele.size["height"]+8000

driver.set_window_size(1920, total_height)      #the trick
time.sleep(2)
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot1.png")

for i in imgsrc2:
    location = i.location 
    size = i.size 
    x = location['x'] 
    y = location['y']
    width = x + size['width'] 
    height = y + size['height'] 
    fullImg = Image.open("screenshot1.png") 
    cropImg = fullImg.crop((x, y, x + width, y + height))
    cropImg.save("\\images\\new-img" + str(i) + ".png")
     

driver.quit()
```

The large screenshot of the whole page is fine but I get cropped images like this one
[image]

Comment: seems like imgsrc2's xpath should be something like "//img..."  Check those webreferences to see if they are the correct ones.

Comment: yeah,  tried that previously and got the same result... :(

Comment: seems like width and height should just be size... not sure why you're adding location coords there... (might be needed for the crop tool you're using, but not before... right now you're adding the coords twice.)  You might also use getRect instead on the webelement.  Should give height, width, x, y...

Comment: btw, I think in some drivers you can take a screenshot of just the element.  element.screenshot_as...

Comment: @pcalkins, thx for your comments. I'll try a few things and see how it turns out!

Comment: @pcalkins, FYI, when I switched to the firefox webdriver (geckodriver) and tried the same code, it worked perfectly well! I'm not sure what makes the Google webdriver not work. It seems the coordinates are all wrong and it takes the wrong screenshots. Thx again for having a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code using the firefox driver:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from PIL import Image
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://superrare.com/features/the-intersection-of-machine-and-artist")
time.sleep(2)                                                                                                            

#the element with longest height on page
ele=driver.find_element("xpath", '//div[@id="root"]')
total_height = ele.size["height"]+12000
time.sleep(2)  

driver.set_window_size(2500, total_height)      #the trick
time.sleep(2)
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot1.png")
time.sleep(3)

imgsrc = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'slide selected')]")))
imgsrc2 = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'slide selected')]")))

time.sleep(10)



for i in imgsrc2:
    location = i.location 
    size = i.size 
    x = location['x'] 
    y = location['y']
    width = x + size['width'] 
    height = y + size['height'] 
    # print(x, y, width, height)
    fullImg = Image.open("screenshot1.png") 
    # cropImg = fullImg.crop((x, y, x + width, y + height))
    cropImg =  fullImg.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))
    cropImg.save("\\images\\new-img" + str(i) + ".png")
     

driver.close()
```